# Drag and Drop Document to Folder

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Hi for the life of me I cannot find a way to create drag and drop from one folder to another in Domino Designer.

I have a 'standard design', Mail In type Inbox Folder, with another Target Folder. Standard left hand Outline with the menu items for each folder. I just want to drag documents from one folder into another utline Entry menu folder. Just like you can with (say) the standard Domino Library template.

I'm missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

[image]O

Comment: I don't understand... this is a default feature... no need to code anything... are you sure, that "Repository" is a folder and not a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders were inside another frame and linking to a framset. Hence my design was wrong.

I did post a comment above but it has been removed!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Designer client, the folders get nested only because of their naming , by using the backslash:

folder1
folder1\subfolder1
folder1\subfolder2
folder2

So if you want to "move" a forder in the tree, you have to rename it in Designer. Or drag and drop it in the Notes client.

Answer (score 0):

There have bee a few issues with Drag and Drop in the last releases of Notes/Domino:

- https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0098154
- https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0093589

These should all be resolved with 12.0.2.